# Oracle Database Query cross two tables, return higher weight from crossed columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Having some difficulties to create a query that crosses two tables and select the highest weight from crossed columns (between dP1 and tP1, dP2 and tP2, dP3 and tP3).

- If in table DETAILS i receive dP1, dP2 and dP3, i must choose the TEMPLATE with tP1=dP1 and tP2=dP2 and tP3=tP3.
- No records found, then choose TEMPLATE with tP1=dP1 and tP2=dP2.
- No records found, then choose TEMPLATE tP1=dP1.
- No records found, then choose the TEMPLATE with no relation on PX.

**Notes**: dPX are sequencial, which means i receive only in DETAILS dP1, or dP1+dP2 or dP1+dP2+dP3. If i receive only a dP2, i will look for the TEMPLATE with no relation on PX.

**Example**:

TABLE DETAILS

```
| BATCH_ID | TEMPLATE_ID | dP1 | dP2 | dP3 |
|   12345  | template_1  |  a  |  b  |  c  |
|   12345  | template_1  |  a  |  b  |     |
|   12345  | template_1  |  a  |     |     |
|   12345  | template_1  |     |     |     |
|   12345  | template_1  |  x  |     |     |
|   12345  | template_1  |     |  y  |     |
|   12345  | template_1  |  a  |  z  |     |
```

TABLE TEMPLATE

```
| TEMPLATE_ID | MESSAGE | tP1 | tP2 | tP3 |
| template_1  |   msg0  |     |     |     |
| template_1  |   msg1  |  a  |     |     |
| template_1  |   msg2  |  a  |  b  |     |
| template_1  |   msg3  |  a  |  b  |  c  |
```

---

Giving the BATCH_ID as input i wish a return of the Query like this:

***`select * from DETAILS d left join TEMPLATE t on d.TEMPLATE_ID=t.TEMPLATE_ID where BATCH_ID='12345'` and ....***

```
| TEMPLATE_ID | MESSAGE | dP1 | dP2 | dP3 | tP1 | tP2 | tP3 |
| template_1  |   msg0  |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| template_1  |   msg1  |  a  |     |     |  a  |     |     |
| template_1  |   msg2  |  a  |  b  |     |  a  |  b  |     |
| template_1  |   msg3  |  a  |  b  |  c  |  a  |  b  |  c  |
| template_1  |   msg0  |  x  |     |     |     |     |     |
| template_1  |   msg0  |     |  y  |     |     |     |     |
| template_1  |   msg1  |  a  |  z  |     |  a  |     |     |
```

Appreciate any help. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: updated with corrected logic and better cost. I'm pretty sure there's a better way to write the priority section, but I need more coffee.

```
select template_id, message, 
    dp1, dp2, dp3, 
    tp1, tp2, tp3
from ( select d.template_id, message, 
    dp1, dp2, dp3, 
    tp1, tp2, tp3,
    case when (dp1 = tp1 and dp2 = tp2 and dp3 = tp3) then 1
         when (dp1 = tp1 and dp2 = tp2 and tp3 is null) then 2
         when (dp1 = tp1 and tp2 is null and tp3 is null) then 3
         when coalesce(tp1,tp2,tp3) is null then 4
         else 5 end as tpriority,
    min(case when (dp1 = tp1 and dp2 = tp2 and dp3 = tp3) then 1
         when (dp1 = tp1 and dp2 = tp2 and tp3 is null) then 2
         when (dp1 = tp1 and tp2 is null and tp3 is null) then 3
         when coalesce(tp1,tp2,tp3) is null then 4
         else 5 end) over (partition by d.template_id, dp1, dp2, dp3) as min_priority
    from DETAILS d
    left join TEMPLATE t
        on d.TEMPLATE_ID = t.TEMPLATE_ID (+)
) v
where tpriority = min_priority
;
```

Output

```
TEMPLATE_ID                    MESSAGE    DP1 DP2 DP3 TP1 TP2 TP3
------------------------------ ---------- --- --- --- --- --- ---
template1                      msg3       a   b   c   a   b   c  
template1                      msg2       a   b       a   b      
template1                      msg1       a   z       a          
template1                      msg1       a           a          
template1                      msg0       x                      
template1                      msg0           y                  
template1                      msg0
```

Comment: Hi kfinity, thank you for your quick feedback. Definitely that is a good query (lacks a bit of performance but not bad). The only thing is missing is the last record on output. Since "DP1=a" and "DP2=z", it should choose the "msg1" because DP1=TP1. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I missed that requirement. Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very very much kfinity! The cost of this query is not that high but it has a nested loop and a full table access (worse case scenario) on TEMPLATE since it is not indexed for template_id. I'm going to do a performance test and add the indexes that may be usefull. Hopefully won't need to adjust query :)

Comment: Thanks once again kfinity. Regards